# Counting the number of input boxes with data

Tags: jquery

How would I keep count of all the `.waypoint-container input` elements that have text entered in them. So far I've managed to figure out how to access each element, but I'm not sure how to add the element that has met the requirement to a "count" once it's been determined.

```
function countActiveWaypoint() {
    // n = 0
    $('.waypoint-container input').each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
             // if the textbox is filled then n+1
             $('#waypoints').val(n);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just count it and return it.

```
function countActiveWaypoint() {
    var count = 0;
    $('.waypoint-container input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
$('#waypoints').val(countActiveWaypoint());
```

Since you are using jQuery you could also make it a little more jQuery by creating a simple jQuery extension. Something like this should suffice (change the name to your liking):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    countNotEmptyInputs: function() {
        var count = 0;
        this.each(function() {
            if ($(this).is("input:text") && $(this).val().length > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }
});

var count = $('.waypoint-container input').countNotEmptyInputs();
$('#waypoints').val(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Find all elements that have a value really quickly:

```js
function countActiveWaypoint() {
  return $('.waypoint-container input[value!=""]').length;
}

$('#waypoints').val(countActiveWaypoint());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="waypoint-container">
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="test 1" />
  <input type="text" value="test 2" />
</div>

<input id="waypoints" type="text" />
```